# Good library for bitsets or bitarrays

Tags: c++, bitset

Hallo all,
I'm looking for some good library, that works with bitsets or bitarrays. Anybody knows something better (or not worse in all cases) then boost::dynamic_bitset? No matter if the library is open source or commercial.

In my project it is a common task to store and work with large bit masks, that contain less number of ones. So they could be compressed well in memory.

Comment: Could you tell us what's wrong with boost's bitsets implementations? It would help.

Comment: Or even what's wrong with `std::bitset`.

Comment: Or rather, what functionality you require that's not provided.

Comment: +1 I'm interested in that too. Concatenating serveral small bitsets into one big bitset is very slow when using `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset`

Comment: Another disadvantage is that both store their data bigendian but their toString() returns a string which is littleEndian... This does not make things easier when one has to look if every bit is at its place

Comment: Well, my program should work with bit masks of size 500 000 000 (not only one but several), but as usual only a few (comparing to the mask's size) bits are actually set to 1. So, such mask could be stored more efficiently than just using 1 byte of memory per 8 bits. I'm more interested in space compression, than in an operation speed, and looking for libraries that can do it well.

Answer (score 7):

There are several implementations of compressed bitvectors available. They usually feature a run length encoding together with and/or/xor/not operations which work on the compressed form.

So the benefits are:

- smaller space usage (for sparse bitsets, as in your use case)
- very fast bit operations (because they work on words and are far more cpu cache friendly)

and on the downside:

- slower bit access (iteration required to find a bit at a specific position)

Some implementations i am aware of (there are others i am sure):

[Fastbit](https://sdm.lbl.gov/fastbit/)
Is in fact a database using a bitvector index. The compressed bitvector class can be used directly (without the indexing)

[Lemur bitmapindex](http://code.google.com/p/lemurbitmapindex/) Another implementation of the EWAH encoding introduced by Fastbit

[Compressed bitvector by koen.vandamme](http://users.telenet.be/koen.vandamme1/c_tools/bitplatforms/_index.htm)
Never tried it...but only two headers and a cpp file. So not much effort to give it a try.

[Bitmagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/)
Full blown package implementing several compressed bitvectors including hardware support (sse2, ...)

Hope this helps,

Roland

Answer (score 0):

How about MiniSAT libraries?

http://minisat.se/

I recall this having a simple implementation for bit arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is space optimization, then std::vector provides a vector specialization that's optimized for space.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

and C++ standard 23.2.5

No idea if this is better than boost:dynamic_bitset, but it's worth investigating if you haven't already looked into it.